# Custom caption prefix

Tags: latex, listings

When using:

```
\begin{listing}
...
\caption{foo}
\end{listing}
```

The caption will say: `Listing x: foo`. How can I replace the word `Listing` with something else?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using minted (I am, and my source looks like yours), you may want to try

```
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Some fancy listing}
```

Comment: works for me in 2022, in case someone was wondering

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read the manual

http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf

page 32

```
\begin{listing}[caption=Some fancy listing]
```

or try

```
\begin{listing}[title=Some fancy listing]
```

or try

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{A funny listing}
```

Minimal example that works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Something}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=wwww]
xxxx
\end{lstlisting}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The last one seems to be what I need. I tried it, but it doesn't work. I pasted it just below `\usepackage{listings}`. Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Some more info would be helpful. Which package do you use? I did not find a "listing" environment in package listings, nor does it give me a caption.